# Flask-SQLAlchemy sqlite crashing on db.session.commit()

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have the following code. I'm trying to insert user data into a sqlite database using SQLAlchemy it crashes when I give the following command in the python prompt. I'm trying to add the users to the database then once I commit I want to query the database and display the information to verify it got inserted into the database. For now I have it only displaying to the prompt I haven't developed any methods to render it.

```
from DIRT import db
db.create_all()
from DIRT import User, Post
user_1 = User(username="John Wick", email="jw@gmail.com", password="password")
user_2 = User(username="John Snow", email="js@gmail.com", password="password")
db.session.add(user_1)
db.session.add(user_2)
db.session.commit()
```

*Below is my code for the DIRT.py*

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from MyForms import RegisterForm, LoginForm


app = Flask(__name__)

# creating secret numbers to prevent modified cookie attack, or cross-site attacks
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '4b15463cce52d7b99874c9fb2312d580'

# database uri
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///dirt.db'

# database
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


# user model for the sql database
# class User(db.Model):
#   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
#  username = db.Column(db.String(25), unique=True, nullable=False)
#  email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
#  image_file = db.Column(db.String(25), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
#    password = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
#    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)

#   def __repf__(self):
#       return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}')"


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"


posts = [
    {
        'author': 'Cloud Strife',
        'title': 'Where do we find Aeris..',
        'content': 'So we are trying to find her',
        'date_posted': 'November 12, 2019'

    },
    {
        'author': 'Cecil Paladin',
        'title': 'Where is the crystal sword',
        'content': 'Trying to find the crystal bridge',
        'date_posted': 'July 10, 2019'

    }

]


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)


@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template('about.html', title='About')


@app.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegisterForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash(f'Account created for {form.username.data} successfully!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)


# @app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
# def login():
#    MyForm = LoginForm()
#   return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=MyForm)

@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.email.data == 'onyxbird@hotmail.com' and form.password.data == 'sandman23':
            flash(f'{form.email.data} has logged in!', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check email and password', 'danger')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='8080')
    # above is production mode
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is the errors I'm getting:

```
*db.session.commit()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\onyxb\PycharmProjects\DIRT\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\scoping.py", line 162, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\onyxb\PycharmProjects\DIRT\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1027, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "C:\Users\onyxb\PycharmProjects\DIRT\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 492, in commit
    self._assert_active(prepared_ok=True)
  File "C:\Users\onyxb\PycharmProjects\DIRT\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 288, in _assert_active
    raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: user.image_file
[SQL: INSERT INTO user (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('John Wick', 'jw@gmail.com', 'password')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj) (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/7s2a)*
```

Comment: so now I'm getting the following error.

**bold**
 return self.connection.cursor(*args, **kwargs)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (sqlite3.ProgrammingError) SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 20908 and this is thread id 5756. **bold**

Comment: Looks like the actual DB table has a column `image_file` that has a NOT NULL constraint, which is missing from your model definition. The missing column seems to be defined in a previous version of the model (commented out). Note that removing and altering columns in the model definition does not modify the created table in the DB. You have to migrate the table to match the new model.

Comment: Thank you I fixed that issue. Now I'm getting the following error:
`code`
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (sqlite3.ProgrammingError) SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 21108 and this is thread id 10260.
[SQL: SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.username AS user_username, user.email AS user_email, user.password AS user_password 
FROM user]
[parameters: [immutabledict({})]]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
`code`

Comment: To fix the above mentioned error I had to change a attribute in the database to the followiing. `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///dirt.db?check_same_thread=False'`